# Including local jar file in Clojure project

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have used the leiningen plugin localrepo to install my own java class as a jar file. This seems to have worked fine since it gets installed into `~/.m2` as evident by the command below.

```
lein localrepo list | grep myJunk
$ myJunk/exp (1.0.0)
```

I then include the following line in `project.clj`

```
[myJunk/exp "1.0.0"]
```

Finally I include the following in my `.clj` file.

```
(ns exp.exp-test
  (:use [exp.core]
        [clojure.test])
  (:import [com.curry.expenses Expense]))
```

When I try to run the import i get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.curry.expenses.Expense
```

This is the beginning of my java class from which I have generated the jar file.

```
package com.curry.expenses;

public class Expense { ... }
```

Now my question is what am I missing in order to be able to use this class in my Clojure project?

Update:
This is the content of the generated `.pom` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myJunk</groupId>
  <artifactId>exp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <name>exp</name>
</project>
```

Comment: Hard to tell what is wrong here. IIRC import statements have to be in parantheses like this: (:import (com.curry.expenses Expense)). If that makes no difference, maybe you can post the generated .pom file for your jar?

Comment: I have updated the question with the content of the pom file. using parentheses did not make a difference.

Comment: Did you look inside the generated jar file? Is the class in the path that mirrors the package name inside the jar?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? How can i check this, what should i look for?

Comment: Open the generated jar file and see if there is a path like src/com/curry/expenses with an Expense.class inside.

Comment: No, Expense.class is located directly under the jar file. If i do unzip Expense.jar I get a folder called META-INF and Expense.jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, So we spotted at least one error.

You have a project and inside that project is a class `FooBar.java` with a namespace `foo.bar.baz` then it is expected that the file `Foobar.java` is in a folder structure like this: `foo/bar/baz` mirroring the namespace, most probably lying in a `src` folder.

Generating a jar from that will also have that path inside the jar and inside the path under `foo/bar/baz` will be the FooBar.class.

This is nothing specific to clojure but to java in general and clojure expects the same folder structure.